# How to Export Firebase Cloud Functions Logs to a file?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to download cloud functions logs as a text file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Using [Stackdriver logging UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/logs?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com), you can view your logs and click on the "Download logs" button to download you latest logs in JSON or CSV format (up to 300 logs at the moment. If you need more, consider [exporting](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/) your logs).
- Using Firebase CLI, you should be able to pipe the output of the functions:log command to a text file:`firebase functions:log > logs.txt`

Comment: Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```sh
gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloud_function" --limit 1000 --format json > logs.json
```

To get the last 1000 log entries. You can also use `--freshness=1d` to get entries not older than one day. More info with and examples with `gcloud logging read --help`